# Capturing return key causes loop to run twice in curses, python

Tags: python, curses

Capturing the return key causes my loop to run twice, other keys only return once. Code below captures arrow keys and return key, with a counter to visualise how many times the code is run. Upon hitting the return key, the counter will advance by 2 instead of 1.

Using pycharm on mac os, with pycharm's environment set to emulate the terminal in the output console.

Thanks for any help.

```
import curses
from curses import wrapper


def main(stdscr):
    # Clear screen
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.addstr("test")
    stdscr.addstr(3, 3, "x")
    stdscr.addstr(6, 6, "x")
    stdscr.clear()
    n = 0
    while True:

        c = stdscr.getch()
        stdscr.clear()
        stdscr.addstr(str(n))
        stdscr.move(2, 0)
        if c == curses.KEY_UP:
            stdscr.addstr("up")
        elif c == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            stdscr.addstr("down")
        elif c == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            stdscr.addstr("left")
        elif c == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            stdscr.addstr("right")
        elif c == curses.KEY_ENTER or c == 10 or c == 13:
            stdscr.addstr("enter")

        n +=1

wrapper(main)
```

Comment: It's working correctly for me

Comment: Seems it works properly outside of pycharm. Would love to know why pycharm does this though...

Comment: At a guess, perhaps pycharm is sending a CRLF (two characters) when you press Enter? Anyway, it would be easier to see what was happening if you didn't clear the screen after each key press -- add a "\n" to those addstr() calls, and keep a running tally.